# Python - File to Dictionary with specific substrings for key value pairs

Tags: python, compare, comparison, substring

I have a text file that looks like :

```
AAAAA123123423452452BBBASDASAS323423423432
BBBBB453453453466123AAAAADDFFG6565656565665
```

...

I want to create a dictionary out of this, with keys the slices of each line like this :

file.txt :

```
hash[123123] = "BBBASD"
hash[453453] = "AAAAAD"
```

I ve written the following try, but it doesnt work so far. Prints nothing :

```
myhash{}
with open('file.txt') as fi:
    for life in fi:
        key = [line:6:13]
        value = [line:21:27]
        myhash[key] = value

print(myhash)
```

Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
myhash = {}
with open('file.txt') as fi:
    for line in fi.readlines():
        key = line[5:11]
        value = line[20:26]
        myhash[key] = value

print(myhash)
```

You can get [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) about string slicing in Python.

Comment: Fix: `my hash = {}` with "="